# How to disable trigger when a Cascade On Delete if fired

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, cascade

Let me start out trying to explain… My MSSQL2008 R2 database has two tables, one called *SalesHeader* the other *SalesDetails*. If I delete a header record it cascades and deletes all details related to that header. I also have an on delete trigger on the *SalesDetails* table that renumbers the *DetailNumber* field for the remaining details.

The Cascade on delete worked before I put in the Trigger on the Details table. The trigger works now but I get an error when trying to delete a header record. I can manually disable the delete trigger on details table and the header delete works as expected.

To fix this I am not quite sure whether a new on delete trigger on the header table that would disable the trigger on the details table would work or if there is a way to detect the Cascade on Delete in the Details trigger so the trigger logic could be bypassed. I have read here on SO that *INSTEAD OF DELETE* Triggers are not allowed with Cascade on Delete.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated and code snippets even more so.

Cheers,

SQL Trigger:

```
    USE [MyDatabase]
    GO

    /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[OnDeleteTrigger]    Script Date: 9/11/2014 11:51:40 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO


    -- =============================================
    -- Author:      Randy Gordey
    -- Create date: 08/28/2014
    -- Description: Renumbers the remaining details
    --              when rows are deleted.
    -- =============================================
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[OnDeleteTrigger] 
       ON  [dbo].[SalesDetail] 
       AFTER DELETE
    AS 
    BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    PRINT 'Delete Trigger Fired'
    DECLARE @ID int
    DECLARE @RowNum int
    DECLARE @TransactionNumber int

    -- Gets the TransactionNumber from the deleted row
    SET @TransactionNumber = (SELECT
       intTransactionNumber
    FROM DELETED)

    DECLARE myCursor CURSOR

    /** Gets a collection of the detail lines for this Transaction **/
    LOCAL SCROLL STATIC FOR SELECT
       intDetailNumber,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY intDetailNumber) AS 'RowNum'
    FROM SalesDetail
    WHERE intTransactionNumber = @TransactionNumber;

    OPEN myCursor;

    -- Grabs the first row
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @ID, @RowNum;

    -- Begin Loop
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    /** Updates Database: Setting new Detail Number for each row. **/
    UPDATE SalesDetail
    -- intDetailNumber is part of the PrimaryKey but it is not
    -- set as an identity, so we can still change it.
       SET intDetailNumber = @RowNum
       WHERE intDetailNumber = @ID
       AND intTransactionNumber = @TransactionNumber;

    -- Grabs the next row
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @ID, @RowNum;

    END;
    CLOSE myCursor;
    DEALLOCATE myCursor;

    END
    GO
```

Comment: Can you show definition of your Trigger ?

Comment: Perhaps you should remove the cascade delete and put a trigger on the header that both removes and renumbers.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance @Steve, could you explain how one trigger can do booth?

Comment: You can write whatever code you want in your trigger. `Update PerentTable Set SomeField = (Select SUM(DetailField) from ChildTable) FROM Deleted ...` and the a `Delete From ChildTable where ...` I don't understand the confusion. You obviously do a lot in your current ChildTable Delete Trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my fix.

```
    SET @Count = (SELECT
    COUNT(*)
    FROM DELETED)

    -- We want to break for multiple rows (ON DELETE CASCADE)
    IF (@Count > 1) RETURN
```

I only delete single rows from the ChildTable at a time. I also want to keep the cascade on delete - as my ChildTable has Children of its own.